# Unable to load libavcodec

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I've compiled **ffmpeg** on Ubuntu using `gcc-arm-linux-androideabi` and `NDK` and copied the resulting directories into my android project (jni) on Windows. In the android make file, I've declared the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
FFMPEG_DIR := ffmpeg

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE =: libavcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FFMPEG_DIR)/lib/$(LOCAL_MODULE).a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

The project builds fine, but as soon as I call `System.loadLibrary("libavcodec")`, the following exception gets thrown:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError [...] findLibrary returned null [...]
```

What could be wrong in here?

**Edit**

I just noticed `make` returned the following:

```
make.exe: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

What could that mean?